# Condition on $\beta$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Let $f(x)$ be a function such that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=1$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)=\beta$. Then **(1)** $\beta > 1$, **(2)** $\beta$ must be $0$, **(3)** $\beta$ need not be $0$ but $|\beta| < 1$, **(4)** $\beta < -1$.

How I proceed: Take $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ then $f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}$. Here $\beta=0$.So,**(1)** and **(4)** is not true.I am stuck between **(2)** and **(3)**. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, to satisfy the condition $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$, your choice of $f$ could be corrected as $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+1$.

Secondly, by [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), for every $x$, there exists $c_x\in [x,x+1]$, such that $f'(c_x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$. Then
$$\beta=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(c_x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x+1)-f(x))=0.$$

Comment: you are right.Thank you.

Comment: @Argha: You are welcome!